# How Can i use jQuote in my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

**How Can i use jQuote in my HTML file?**

Hi,

Can anyone please guide me to how to use jquote in my project.

Comment: look at the site http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote/ it has example on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include below javascript library in project first.

```
https://github.com/aefxx/jQote2/blob/master/jquery.jqote2.min.js
```